# Как добавить значение в список словарей сохранив при этом старые значения

Tags: python

Подскажите, как добавить значение уже в имеющийся список состоящий из словарей.

```
Хочу добавить значение из lost:
my_list[{.....},
        {fio=' ',
        tel = значение из Lost}
]

    my_list = [
          dict(fio=item['attr']['name'],
          tel = int(item['attr']['number'])
for item in res_data
]
data_list = []
for  res in my_list:
     data_list.append(res['tel']
lost = list(set(range(min(data_list), max(data_list)+1))-set(data_list)
#в lost может быть не одно значение.
```

Comment: Приведите более-менее воспроизводимую структуру исходных данных и результата. Это поможет как-то ответить на Ваш вопрос.

Comment: list[{fio: 'string', tel: int}, fio: 'string', tel: int}...]

Answer (score 0):

for i in lost_data:
persons_list.append(dict(fio=' ',number=i))